# php check the date is Saturday

Tags: php, if-statement

how to check if the date is saturday.

```
<input id="datePicker" name="datePicker" type="text" class="textinput date-pick">
```

my code:

```
if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this Saturday')) == $_SESSION['search_date']) {
  echo 'Event this saturday'; 
} else {
  echo 'Event on the others day';
}
```

above code echoing only for the next week event! if i search for week after or 3 week etc, is not showing the result?

Comment: What do you want to do if the date is not Saturday, instead of checking? (Or did you mean "whether"? :P)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

take a look at [date()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in the php-documentation. you chould change your code to something like this:

```
if(date('w', strtotime($_SESSION['search_date'])) == 6) {
  echo 'Event is on a saturday'; 
} else {
  echo 'Event on the others day';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
if(date("w",$timestamp)==6)
    echo "Saturday";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
`date('w', strtotime($_SESSION['search_date']))` should give the weekday. Check if it's 6, wich is saturday.

Answer (score 0):

date('l') returns a textual representation of the day in question, so I'd do this:

```
$date = strtotime($_SESSION['search_date']);
if (date('l', $date) == 'Saturday'){
 // you know the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Just sharing

//these lines of codes returns "Holidays: Sat & Sun" based on given start and end date

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala Lumpure');

$startDate = '2014-01-03';

$endDate = '2014-01-23';

$st_arr = explode('-', $startDate);

$en_arr = explode('-', $endDate);

$st_tot = intval($st_arr[0]+$st_arr[1]+$st_arr[2]);

$en_tot = intval($en_arr[0]+$en_arr[1]+$en_arr[2]);

$count = 0;

for( $i = $st_tot ; $i <= $en_tot ; $i++ ) {

//Increase each day by count: goes according to the calender val

    $date = strtotime("+" .$count." day", strtotime($startDate));
    $x = date("Y-m-d", $date);

    if(date("w",strtotime($x))==6 || date("w",strtotime($x))==0 ) {
        echo "holiday - ". $x. '<br>';
    } else {
        echo "Nope - ". $x. '<br>';
    }

    $count++;
}
```